# SharePoint 2013 App on Google Chrome

Tags: 2013, app, browser-compatibility

I added an app to my Site,it works fine on IE11 but if I try to use it from Chrome Browser (`v34.0.1847.116 m`) the browser asks me for *user and password* and never go through to the app. Even with correct credentials .

I have added the site to the trusted zone.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like a loopback check problem, http://www.jeremytaylor.net/2010/05/24/sharepoint-disable-loopback-check-disableloopbackcheck-dword-in-registry/

Comment: It might as well be the loopback problem as @MuhammadRaja points out. This does depend on what type of app you have (SharePoint hosted/Autohosted/provider hosted), but I imagine you have Windows authentication, and so I would use fiddler to compare IE11 NTML authetication compared to how Chrome does it - you might get some clues

Comment: It is a SharePoint hosted app and yes I am using Windows Authentication. I can login to the site but then no to the app (same credentials)